# Content of PHP won't show in jQuery dialog

Tags: php, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm trying to load the content of a PHP file in a jQuery UI dialog, but the dialog won't open. 
If I debug the code with FireBug, there seems to be an break without any error report on the following line `$('#formDialog_open').load($(this).attr('href'), function()`

**HTML**

```
<div id="formDialog_open" class="widget grid6" title="Dialog with form elements">
//my php codes
</div>
```

**hyperlink what fires the dialogbox**

```
<a href="edit.php?id=' .$aRow['id']. '" id="form" class="tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Edit">
```

**The Javascript**

```
    $('#form').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#formDialog_open').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){

            $('#formDialog_open').dialog({
                title: 'User Administration',
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                hide: 'fade',
                width:350,
                height:275,
            });//end dialog   
        });
    });
```

Comment: what element with id 'formDialog_open' in your html? is it a hyperlink ? paste your html also

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you following `

```
$("#button1").click(function () {

        $('#formDialog_open').dialog({
            title: 'User Administration',
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            hide: 'fade',
            width:350,
            height:275,
        });//end dialog   
});`
```

Check it out and find out that it seems click event is not execute. So I have given a code for the #button1 click event.

Also you can use follow[Jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and [Click Event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) Jquery documents